# API not exists in AVD manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have sdk 8,10 and 23. but in avd manager only 8 and 10 are shown
sdk:
 [image]

avd manager:

[image]

why? I have API 23 but why doesn't it exist in avd manager?

system images.which one should I install?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVD check for System Images installed . You have to install them at the level you wish use them. API SDK level are to build/compile project instead

Comment: can you help me to choose the right system image among these options?

Comment: If you have a PC with Hardware emulation (VT-x, AMD-V , be sure option is enabled on BIOS), I suggest to use "Intel x86 Atom System Image" of the level you need . "ARM EABI System Image" is too slow because no Hardware Accelerated option. Other system Images are these with Google API embedded or Wear/TV/Auto Images. If you would try something more quick to start and run check my guide (https://alramacciotti.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/using-androidx86-virtualbox-as-emulator-for-eclipseadb/ ) for use AndroidX86 on VirtualBox with Eclipse/AS

Comment: For better preformed emulators you could try last beta Android Studio 2.0+ . It sports a new emulator technology that run very quick

Comment: excuse me, my system is x64. does to related to this option? some option are x86 and some are x64.

Comment: My PC too, and I use x86 images. x64 Images are newer then first ones and most of target devices are still 32bit so I prefer use them

Comment: so x86 doesn't mean that my PC should be x86 and  api for avi is related to system image